# Proof that $1-\frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, consider the function $f_n(x)=e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ over $[0;1]$.

I have to prove the following inequality : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*:0 \leq f_n(0)-f_n(1) \leq \frac{1}{n!}$. By taking the derivative and showing the function is decreasing over $[0;1]$, I am able to prove the LHS, however I struggle to prove the RHS... How would you do?

Edit: The point of this question is to then prove the convergence of the infinite serie $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ to $e$, which means such a result is not supposed to be used.

Comment: Try to show it by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the derivative, we have
$$
f_n'(x) = - e^{-x} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} + e^{-x} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = - e^{-x} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} + e^{-x} \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!} = -e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!} \leq 0
$$
for any $x \in [0,1]$.

Thus, as you noticed, the function is decreasing in $[0,1]$, and you get $f_n(0) \geq f_n(1)$.

Now, from the mean-value theorem there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that
$$
f_n(0) - f_n(1) = -f_n(c)' = e^{-c} \frac{c^n}{n!} \leq e^{-1} \frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}
$$

Edit: For completeness, the inequality $e^{-c} \frac{c^n}{n!} \leq e^{-1} \frac{1}{n!}$ follows from the fact that $g(x) = e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is an increasing function for $x \in [0,1]$, as
$$
g'(x) = -e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!} +  e^{-x} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = e^{-x}x^{n-1}\frac{n - x}{n!} \geq 0
$$

Comment: Clever use of the MVT, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Proof without induction :**

One has $$e- \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(k+n+1)!} \quad \quad (*)$$

But for every $k \geq 0$, one has $$\dfrac{(k+n+1)!}{(n+1)!k!} = {k+n+1 \choose n+1} \geq 1, \quad \text{so} \quad \dfrac{1}{(k+n+1)!} \leq \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!k!}$$

Then $(*)$ becomes $$e- \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k!} \leq \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!k!} = \dfrac{e}{(n+1)!}, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \boxed{1- \dfrac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k!} \leq \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}}$$

(which is a little bit more precise than the inequality you want to prove).

Comment: See my edit, I cannot use the fact that $e=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ (my fault, I should have mentioned it before)

Comment: If you cannot, what is your definition of $e$ ??

Comment: I just finished high-school, and here in France, $e$ is taught as equal to $exp(1)$, with $exp$ being the exponential function, defined as the unique solution of the differential equation $y'=y$ satisfying the initial condition $y(0)=1$. Other definitions such as this infinite series are not seen until higher education.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward proof uses Lagrange error bound for the Maclaurin series for $x \mapsto e^x$.

This bound shows us that $|e - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!}| \leq \frac{e}{(n+ 1)!}$. We can drop the absolute value sign to conclude $e - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{e}{(n+ 1)!}$.

Then dividing both sides by $e$, we have $1 - \frac{1}{e} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{(n + 1)!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: I'm afraid those concepts are unfamiliar to me... My question is supposed to be solved using "basic" calculus.

Comment: @LucasMartiniano I would call the Lagrange error basic since it is typically covered in AP calculus, but perhaps I overstate the simplicity of it. At any rate, it is quite easy to prove the Lagrange error bound is correct, and many of the other proofs I’m seeing simply take that proof and apply it to the particular case you’ve presented.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the most elementary proof of the result. We want to prove that

$e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k!}\leq e\dfrac{1}{n!}$

which is,  $\,\,\,\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{n!}{k!}\leq\,e\,\,$ i.e.

$\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+...\leq\,e$.

We observe that $\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\leq\,\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} , \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\,\leq\,\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{3}},$ e.t.c.

so we obtain a geometric series $\dfrac{1}{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}})$=$\dfrac{1}{n}\,\leq\,e$  and the result is proved!!

Comment: See my edit, I cannot use the fact that $e=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ (my fault, I should have mentioned it before)

Comment: It is very easy to prove this, Define $f_{n}(x)=1+x+\dfrac{x^{2}}{2!}+....+\dfrac{x^{n}}{n!}$ and use Taylor's theorem with a remainder. Then $e^{x}=f_{n}(x)+\dfrac{e^{\xi}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$. So on any closed bounded set $sup|e^{x}-f_{n}(x)|$=sup$|\dfrac{e^{\xi}}{(n+1)!}|$$|x^{n+1}|$ and the latter $\to 0$ on closed bounded sets! So$ f_{n}(x)\to e^{x}$ uniformly and hence $\sum_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}=e$ setting $x=1$

Comment: My question is taken from a high-school exercise book, hence Taylor's theorem cannot be used, which is why I accepted Frederico's answer.